# Am I in or Am I out?

Tags: mathematics, computer-puzzle

There is a very simple logic-based programming language called **M35**. Here is how simple it is.

It has $3$ (yes three) instructions:

1. Load *acc* with $1$
2. Add $3$ to *acc*
3. Multiply *acc* by $5$

Bob wants to know if particular values for *acc* can be achieved by **M35**, specifically $2^k$.

Comment: Do you mean 10'000 or 10 to the power of k?

Comment: $10^k$ not $10k$ (in binary)

Comment: For which values of k?  4 can obviously be achieved.  2 obviously can't.

Comment: Your comment and original question refer to 10^k, but your most recent edit refers to 2^k - which are you after?

Comment: @MarkBannister; $2^k$ for the M35 because 10^k is always true by instruction 2

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the worst programming language.

Comment: @IanMacDonald; there was the prototype, the **M**

Comment: What happened to M1 - M34?

Comment: What is the initial state of the accumulator?  If we assume that it is initialized to $-1$, then **$2$** (i.e., $2^1$) can be achieved, as well.

Comment: Well, now we *have* to use this for a PPCG challenge.

Comment: @TracyCramer; they were deemed inferior

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that if $k$ is even, then $2^k=2^{2m}=4^m$ which is congruent to 1 (mod 3), so we can write

$$2^k = 1 + 3h$$

so you just need to apply operation (2) sufficiently many times. This works for any non-negative, even $k$.

If $k$ is odd then $2^k=2^{1+2m} = 2\cdot 4^m$ which is congruent to 2 (mod 3) so we can write

$$2^k = 2 + 3h = 8 + 3(h-2)$$

Since we can reach 8 by applying operation (3) followed by operation (2), you simply need to apply operation (2) another $h-2$ times to reach $2^k$. This works for any positive, odd $k$ except for $k=1$.

This demonstrates that $2^k$ is reachable for $k=0$ and for any $k>1$.

---

**Edit** - by congruence, I mean congruence in the sense of [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_relation).

Comment: Very nice answer. However, I know the term 'congruent' only in connection to [geometry](http://www.mathopenref.com/congruent.html). Could you provide a link to the meaning you use here, please? (This is a puzzle site not a maths site, so *some of us* need a bit more detail...)

Comment: I think [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html) is helpful. With that, and the assumption that *h* is an integer value, I could follow your argument.

Comment: How many bits does this language use for storing integers?  It's possible you could reach 1 or 2 by overflowing the variable...